# CkFinder 3 не загружает большие файлы

Tags: php, javascript, ckeditor

**CkFinder** Загружает максимум 128 мб причем выяснил что зависит от оперативной памяти. Ставлю в php.ini `memory_limit = 8G`, по факту 1Gb в итоге загружает файлы максимального размера 1Gb.
На параметры `post_max_size = 10G` и `upload_max_filesize = 10G` не обращает внимание.

Как исправить чтоб **Ckfinder** не использовал память, а грузил в temp папку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему путем правки **php.ini**. Проблема была во времени работы скрипта. В папке **/tmp** оставались недогруженные файлы.

**max_execution_time** = 86400  #на 24 часа

**max_input_time**  = 86400

**upload_max_filesize** = 40G

**post_max_size** = 40G

memory_limit = 40G #Ckfinder берет максимальный размер загружаемого файла отсюда